# "fork: Resource temporarily unavailable" from git in MacOS El Capitan

Tags: bash, git, sudo, profile

Sometimes when I am using Git and cannot do a `sudo` command, it reports

> `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`

What does this mean, and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fork error usually means the parent program was unable to execute one-or-more child processes because a resource limit was reached, either the maximum allowed number of processes (the `EAGAIN` error) or maximum allowed amount of memory (`ENOMEM` error). The man page of Fork(2) says:

```
 Fork() will fail and no child process will be created if:

 [EAGAIN]  The system-imposed limit on the total number of processes under execution would
           be exceeded.  This limit is configuration-dependent.

 [EAGAIN]  The system-imposed limit MAXUPRC (<sys/param.h>) on the total number of pro-
           cesses under execution by a single user would be exceeded.

 [ENOMEM]  There is insufficient swap space for the new process.
```

There are several ways that limits are imposed on OS X:

- Per-session limit set by the `ulimit` command. You can view current limit by running `ulimit -a` and set a new limit, e.g., `ulimit -u 1000` to set the max proc limit to 1000. This limit remains until the current termian session ends.
- System limits are set using launchd, in a file at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist` (only OS X 10.9+).

For more detail see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/221988/88511).